# Extract a block from file between two lines

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I have a file/output containing this :

```
igw_id = igw-96788cf1
private_route_tables_ids = [
    rtb-c2adcda4,
    rtb-c5a3c3a3,
    rtb-c4adcda2
]
private_subnets_cidrs_ipv4 = [
    10.20.10.0/24,
    10.20.11.0/24,
    10.20.12.0/24
]
private_subnets_ids = [
    subnet-6057333b,
    subnet-6be7bf0c,
    subnet-f13419b8
]
public_route_tables_ids = [
    rtb-74a9c912,
    rtb-c5adcda3,
    rtb-2aabcb4c
]
public_subnets_cidrs_ipv4 = [
    10.20.0.0/24,
    10.20.1.0/24,
    10.20.2.0/24
]
public_subnets_ids = [
    subnet-6157333a,
    subnet-17e7bf70,
    subnet-303f1279
]
```

I would like to extract all public subnet id and print them without, and white space.

I used this regex

```
sed -n '/public_subnets_ids/{:a;N;/\]/!ba;s/[[:space:]]//g;s/,/\n/g;s/.*public_subnets_ids\|\].*//g;p}' my_file.txt
```

And the output is :

```
=[subnet-6157333a
subnet-17e7bf70
subnet-303f1279
```

But I would like to get this instead:

```
subnet-6157333a
subnet-17e7bf70
subnet-303f1279
```

In fact I told sed to replace spaces and newlines with nothing `(s/[[:space:]]//g)` and then it also replace the first new line and then brings the first subnet up, so I would to process the regex after the first newline and when I try this

```
sed -n '/public_subnets_ids = \[[\n\r\s]+\\n/{:a;N;/\]/!ba;s/[[:space:]]//g;s/,/\n/g;s/.*public_subnets_ids\|\].*//g;p}' my_file.txt
```

It gives no ouput, means it doesn't match anything.

Please can help improve the above regex to give only subnets ids in seperated lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach this sed:

```
sed -n '/public_subnets_ids/,/]/{//!{s/[ ,]*//g;p;}}' file
```

- `'/public_subnets_ids/,/]/`: from line containing `public_subnets_ids` up to next line containing `]`
- `//!`: in matching lines, except those matching the addresses
- `//!{s/[ ,]*//g;p;}`: removes commas and space characters and output result

Comment: Yes, less difficult and works...
And how if I would like to modify the above command `sed -n '/public_subnets_ids/,/]/{//!{s/[ ,]*//g;p;}}' file` to get only  the first subnet ID? How to get only the second subnet id..... and so on....

Comment: I know I can pipe and use another command on the sed ouput, but I would like to do it directly in the above sed command.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/^]/{f=0} f{$1=$1; sub(",",""); print} 
       /public_subnets_ids/{f=1}' file

subnet-6157333a
subnet-17e7bf70
subnet-303f1279
```

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may also help you in same.

```
awk '/public_subnets_ids/{getline;while($0 !~ /]/){gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|,/,"");print;getline}}'   Input_file
```

***EDIT:*** Adding non-one liner form of solution with explanation also on same.

```
awk '
/public_subnets_ids/{         ##Searching for string public_subnets_ids in a line, if yes then do following.
 getline;                     ##Going to next line by using getline utility of awk.
 while($0 !~ /]/){            ##Using while loop till a line is NOT having ]
   gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|,/,"");##Globally substituting initial space and comma with NULL in all lines here.
   print;                     ##Printing the lines here.
   getline                    ##using getline cursor will move to next line of Input_file.
}
}'  Input_file                ##Mentioning the Input_file name here.
```